# Files for Jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Im planning to jquery ui and would like to understand what files needs to be included....

As per this document `https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/`, once I unzip the files, I should see the following folder,

```
/css/
/development-bundle/
/js/
index.html
```

but I dont see the following folder when I download version jquery-ui-1.9.0.. I only see the following files. what needs to be included in my files to make dialogs work?

```
AUTHORS.txt           ui.effect-drop.jquery.json
demos                 ui.effect-explode.jquery.json
external              ui.effect-fade.jquery.json
grunt.js              ui.effect-fold.jquery.json
jquery-1.8.2.js           ui.effect-highlight.jquery.json
MANIFEST              ui.effect.jquery.json
MIT-LICENSE.txt           ui.effect-pulsate.jquery.json
package.json              ui.effect-scale.jquery.json
README.md             ui.effect-shake.jquery.json
tests                 ui.effect-slide.jquery.json
themes                ui.effect-transfer.jquery.json
ui                ui.menu.jquery.json
ui.accordion.jquery.json      ui.mouse.jquery.json
ui.autocomplete.jquery.json   ui.position.jquery.json
ui.button.jquery.json         ui.progressbar.jquery.json
ui.core.jquery.json       ui.resizable.jquery.json
ui.datepicker.jquery.json     ui.selectable.jquery.json
ui.dialog.jquery.json         ui.slider.jquery.json
ui.draggable.jquery.json      ui.sortable.jquery.json
ui.droppable.jquery.json      ui.spinner.jquery.json
ui.effect-blind.jquery.json   ui.tabs.jquery.json
ui.effect-bounce.jquery.json  ui.tooltip.jquery.json
ui.effect-clip.jquery.json    ui.widget.jquery.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own custom JQueryUI script using only JS files that you need. Just use [JQueryUI Custom Download](http://jqueryui.com/download/) page and select which elements do you want to include. For a better approach, unselect everything and start selecting only what you need.

http://jqueryui.com/download/

Happy coding!